# Calculate 3 phases VA apparent power from DC load after bridge rectifier

Tags: bridge-rectifier, apparent-power

In a tomatoes greehouse I try to power some high bay led light with 3 phases (400V between each phase: 230VAC*SQRT(3)).
After 3 phases rectifier bridge i use the average DC line about 540V.
All the connected led light devices consume an amount of 5000W.

How can i calculate the 3 phases apparent power (VA) from those 5000W ?
I tried this but i'm not sure:
Pfactor = 3/pi, so Papp = 5000/(3/pi) = 5236 VA.
Is it right ?

Comment: There are three variables: W (power), VA (apparent power) and VAr (reactive component). You only have one so you can't calculate either of the others. You need to measure one of them.

Comment: When you choose your VA power from your energy provider, you need to give your power consumption before, according to me. So if I need 5000W, how many VA in 3 phase I must ask?

Comment: 5000 W = 5000 VA if the load is resistive. If it's not then you need the to know the power factor to calculate the VA. \$ \pi \$ doesn't enter into it, by the way.

Comment: So you are saying you are using a simple 6-diode rectifier to make your DC?

Comment: Yes, 6 diodes. It works well.